# remove characters by asterisks

Tags: lightning-aura-components

how could I do to remove characters by asterisks.
in Aura Web Component
For example:
I have this input-field:

```
  <lightning:input label="Account Name" type="text" value="{!v.contactEntity.Numbres_c}"/>
```

and that shows me this:
123456

what I want is to change the first 3 characters to asterisks

and it shows something like this:
***456

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For something that customized, you'll need to write your own Lightning Web Component. If you're okay with masking the entire text, you can use `<lightning-input type="password" label="Password"> </lightning-input>` as outlined in [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/documentation).

Comment: But, with shis type="password" , exist any way to put those asterisks but not at all the value? for example: original value: 123456 , value with type:"password": ***456

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, for something that customized, you'll need to write your own Lightning Web Component.